# Change styles of layer list on QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to make it more user-friendly as some of my maps include over 50 layers, and the same font type and colour scheme make it hard to follow for the users.

Is there a way to style the layer list on QGIS and make it more visually appealing and easier to navigate?

To be specific, I am requesting to modify the theme of the layer panel in QGIS. Since there are over 50-100 layers in each project, I would like to make the panel more user-friendly to navigate.
For instance, I want to increase the font size of group names and change the color of sub-groups on the panel (not on canvas).

*This is not related to grouping the layers or color-coding the fields/objects.*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using groups?

Comment: I think my question was unclear earlier. What I meant was that I want to change the styling of the layer panel. I am not looking to change the symbology of the layers themselves, but rather the appearance of the layer list in the panel.

Comment: Have you tried using groups/folders?

Comment: Or are you talking about the layers of the exported georeferenced maps?

Comment: Layer panel on QGIS: layer names are all same font type, font size and colour. I want to manipulate this UI and customize it

Comment: Have you tried using groups/folders for easier user-orientation?

Comment: would that change the styling?

Comment: It will not change the styling - but that is what you want, right? I think your question is a bit confusing, you should add more details and a screenshot to show what you want to change - and what not.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per se as I do not provide a solution, but it is the result of some testing. I thought it should be possible to re-style the layer names using PyQGIS so I did some digging in the API.

The [`QgsLayerTreeModel`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Layer/QgsLayerTreeModel.html) (the model that handles the layers in the Layers Panel) inherits from the [`QAbstractItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html) class. Using the following code to build a custom `QTreeView` and setting its model, the individual items of the model can be extensively customised.

```py
# create a QWidget 
widget = QWidget()

# create a QTreeView as the container for the model
tree_view = QTreeView(widget)

# create a QStandardItemModel and populate it with items
model = QStandardItemModel()
root_item = model.invisibleRootItem()

item1 = QStandardItem("Item 1")
root_item.appendRow(item1)

item2 = QStandardItem("Item 2")
root_item.appendRow(item2)

# set the model for the tree view
tree_view.setModel(model)

# add the tree view to a layout within the QWidget
layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
layout.addWidget(tree_view)

# create indexes for the items (row number, column number within the model)
idx1 = model.index(0, 0)
idx2 = model.index(1, 0)

# style the model items by their index

# change font and font size
model.setData(idx1, QFont('Arial', 20), Qt.FontRole)

# change the background colour
model.setData(idx2, QColor('maroon'), Qt.BackgroundRole)

# change the colour of the text
model.setData(idx2, QColor('white'), Qt.ForegroundRole)

# Show the widget
widget.show()
```

[image]

However, applying the same logic to the `QgsLayerTreeModel` like so:

```
p = QgsProject.instance()
root = p.layerTreeRoot()
model = QgsLayerTreeModel(root)

idx = model.index(0, 0)
model.setData(idx, QColor('maroon'), Qt.BackgroundRole)
```

returns `False` and fails to update the styling of the model item.

```
>>> model.setData(idx, QColor('maroon'), Qt.BackgroundRole)
False
```

It would appear that the `.setData` method of `QgsLayerTreeModel` is not exposed for anything other than `Qt.DisplayRole` (the layer name).

While I cannot answer your question, perhaps this provides some inspiration to someone with a better understanding of these classes to offer a working solution, or some explanation as to why this method does not work.